# Converting linear range into a normal distribution of values

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a linear range of values (0-300) into a bell-curve distribution representing height in inches (22 - 107, with 72 as the mean) in python, but I don't have the mathematical training to understand any of the stuff I am finding on google. Is there some numpy or scipy function that can do this fairly simply?

To give a little more detail, it's for a game where an attribute within the nominal range of 0-300 represents height. So I need to translate that into a bell-curve of height that spans from the smallest to largest possible heights (22 - 107 inches) with 72 inches as the mean.

I can use scipy.stats.norm.pdf to find what I believe is the probability of any given attribute being at that point in the bell curve. If that's what it's doing, though, I then need to get the value of the height from the height bell curve using the pdf as a kind of index. And I can't seem to find anything that does that, short of writing a function that just keeps iterating until it matches, which seems really inefficient.

Looking into this further, I believe what I am trying to do is the opposite of what these tools are for. Rather than feed the tool a data set and extrapolate statistics, I am trying to take a random number and force it into an idealized bell curve distribution of another range of numbers.

Comment: What about the variance?

Comment: I read somewhere that one way to find the 'normal' variance in a hypothetical normal distribution was to divide the range by 4, so that's what I was using. Since I don't actually have a data set on either side, I'm really just looking for something approximate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up doing what my gut instinct was in the first place: I fudged it. Basically I created a function which spits out results that kind of simulate a bell curve:

```
def height_curve(height_score, race_avg = 72):
    if height_score < 30:
        height = (race_avg*.3) + (height_score/150)*race_avg #22 - 36
    elif height_score < 50:
        height = (race_avg*.5) + ((height_score-29)/132)*race_avg #36 - 47
    elif height_score < 100:
        height = (race_avg*.66) + ((height_score-49)/258)*race_avg #48 - 62
    elif height_score < 160:
        height = (race_avg*.86) + ((height_score-99)/240)*race_avg #62 - 80
    elif height_score < 210:
        height = (race_avg*1.11) + ((height_score-159)/602)*race_avg #80 - 86
    elif height_score < 230:
        height = (race_avg*1.19) + ((height_score-209)/364)*race_avg #86 - 90
    else:
        height = (race_avg*1.25) + ((height_score-229)/297)*race_avg #90+ (300 = 107")

    return height
```

Iterated in my character generation algo 100,000 times, it spat out these results, which are not perfect, but are good enough for now. I'll tune more later:

```
How many characters to generate?100000
MIN SET

INTELLECT:      115
STRENGTH:       112
AGILITY:        94
CONSTITUTION:   101
SENSES:         111
APPEARANCE:     96
Height:         5' 9"
Weight:         200 lbs
Reach:          34"
Stamina:        417
Stamina Regen:  19/rd
Vitae:          6667 ml
Vitae Regen:    3 ml/min
Move (walk):    19 sq/rd
Move (jog):     27 sq/rd
Move (run):     36 sq/rd
Eff. Power:     300 PSI
Brawling:       103%


MAX SET

INTELLECT:      140
STRENGTH:       326
AGILITY:        166
CONSTITUTION:   181
SENSES:         166
APPEARANCE:     78
Height:         6' 10"
Weight:         478 lbs
Reach:          41"
Stamina:        657
Stamina Regen:  47/rd
Vitae:          15933 ml
Vitae Regen:    12 ml/min
Move (walk):    53 sq/rd
Move (jog):     80 sq/rd
Move (run):     106 sq/rd
Eff. Power:     2058 PSI
Brawling:       225%


AVG SET

INTELLECT:      137
STRENGTH:       137
AGILITY:        137
CONSTITUTION:   137
SENSES:         137
APPEARANCE:     94
Height:         6' 1"
Weight:         254 lbs
Reach:          36"
Stamina:        548
Stamina Regen:  33/rd
Vitae:          8467 ml
Vitae Regen:    5 ml/min
Move (walk):    36 sq/rd
Move (jog):     55 sq/rd
Move (run):     72 sq/rd
Eff. Power:     557 PSI
Brawling:       137%


MIN ATTRIBUTES

INTELLECT:      76
STRENGTH:       78
AGILITY:        77
CONSTITUTION:   77
SENSES:         78
APPEARANCE:     65
Height:         4' 8"
Weight:         112 lbs
Reach:          28"
Stamina:        315
Stamina Regen:  11/rd
Vitae:          3733 ml
Vitae Regen:    1 ml/min
Move (walk):    8 sq/rd
Move (jog):     13 sq/rd
Move (run):     17 sq/rd
Eff. Power:     161 PSI
Brawling:       77%


MAX ATTRIBUTES

INTELLECT:      382
STRENGTH:       407
AGILITY:        399
CONSTITUTION:   398
SENSES:         415
APPEARANCE:     228
Height:         11' 8"
Weight:         1586 lbs
Reach:          70"
Stamina:        1546
Stamina Regen:  260/rd
Vitae:          52867 ml
Vitae Regen:    99 ml/min
Move (walk):    468 sq/rd
Move (jog):     702 sq/rd
Move (run):     936 sq/rd
Eff. Power:     7540 PSI
Brawling:       400%
```